# Using "cons" without the "::" operator ocaml

Tags: list, ocaml, cons

Is there a way to construct lists in OCaml without using the `::` operator?

For example, I know that normally elements would be concatenated as follows:

```
1::[2; 3; 4]
```

which produces `[1; 2; 3; 4]`.

What I'm wondering is if it's possible to implement a method that takes

```
cons(1 cons(2 cons(3 cons (4 nil))))
```

and outputs the same result, as shown in the [cons Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cons).

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you are looking for `List.cons`. Which allows you to do

```
# List.(cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 (cons 4 []))));;
- : int list = [1; 2; 3; 4]
```

Comment: Thank you! I was aware of the List.cons operator, but didn't know it could be used in this fashion. :)

Comment: List.(...) just opens the List namespace temporarily. It's a short form of writing `List.cons 1 (List.cons 2 (List.cons 3 (List.cons 4 [])))` and more focused than writing `open List`. It's also great for using a modules infix operators like e.g. `Vec2D.(a + b * s)` without disrupting `+` everywhere.